# Linear maps on vectors in general position

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matroids

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $v_1,\dots, v_n \in V$ be a collection of non-zero vectors for which $\dim \text{span}\{v_i, v_j\} =2$ for all $i\neq j \in \{1,\dots, n\}$ (i.e. they are in *2-general position*) and $\dim \text{span} \{v_1,\dots, v_n\} \geq 3$. Does there always exist an index $i \in \{1,\dots, n\}$ and a linear map $\Pi \in L(V)$ with $\ker(\Pi)=\text{span}(v_i)$ such that $\dim \text{span} \{\Pi v_j, \Pi v_k\} =2$ for all $j \neq k \in \{1,\dots, n\} \setminus \{i\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The vectors
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
in $\mathbb{R}^3$ do not satisfy this property.